# Windows Filtering Platform Callout Drivers - Samples, Tutorials, Help

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, networking, driver

I'm trying to write a [Windows Filtering Platform Callout Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms796358.aspx) for a parental control program.  Unfortunately, I've never written a driver before, and the MSDN documentation on it isn't too helpful unless you already know the basics (I'm guessing).

Does anyone know of any good resources on the subject?  Books, online samples, documentation, examples in the Driver Development Kit?

I'm not asking anyone to do my Google searches for me.  I just need advice on the subject.  If someone has been down this road before or knows of a good resource, I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction; even if it's just a good book on developing drivers for Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OSR [(here)](http://www.osronline.com/) is a good resource for information and has some useful tools. The CodeProject [(here)](http://www.codeproject.com/index.aspx?cat=2) has several good series on WDM and WDF drivers with code.

Since the WFP seems to be for Win2k8, Vista, or better, you can use WDF - when you see references to UMDF (user mode) and KMDF, (kernel mode) this is what they are talking about. Using those acronyms may make googling easier.

Using WDF will make things easier.

Do any testing in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and link to OSR.  +1

Answer (score 0):

you can read [Driver Development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-1-Introduction-to-Drivers) tutorial and write a simple driver. There are the best tutorials I have read.